# E488: Trailing Characters error after attempting to install vim-hybrid

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, macvim, iterm2

So I'm trying to use [Vim-Hybrid](https://github.com/w0ng/vim-hybrid) as my native Vim theme but I've been running into a couple issues with it. Everytime I run the vim command now, I've been receiving the following error message:

```
E488: Trailing characters:       </tr>
line 2194:
E488: Trailing characters:       <tr>
line 2195:
```

There's a lot more trailing character errors that are firing but I believe that there might be an error with my ~/.vim/colors/hybrid.vim - which I copied and pasted from the repo into the the respective path.

Here's the content within my .vimrc: I followed the installation instructions, which told me to:

```
Add to ~/.vimrc:

set background=dark
colorscheme hybrid
```

Further down in the instructions, I was also told to add the following:

```
let g:hybrid_custom_term_colors = 1
let g:hybrid_reduced_contrast = 1 " Remove this line if using the 
default palette.
colorscheme hybrid
```

My .vimrc currently looks like this now:

```
let g:hybrid_custom_term_colors = 1
let g:hybrid_reduced_contrast = 1
set background=dark
colorscheme hybrid
```

Any idea what went wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

*Ninja Edit: Forgot to mention that I'm using iTerm!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently copy and pasted some html code into your colorscheme file. If you open the file in [github](https://github.com/w0ng/vim-hybrid/blob/master/colors/hybrid.vim), click on the [RAW link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/w0ng/vim-hybrid/master/colors/hybrid.vim) and copy paste again and make sure to overwrite the previous version. (Even better would be to simply download that file using wget or similar)

Comment: that solved it! kinda weird how it served html the first time i did it. many thanks christian!